# Using Git in PhpStorm

Tags: git, version-control, phpstorm

I am using git as a VCS in PhpStorm. It seems to work fine. But when I change a file it does not show under `Right click -> Git -> Show History`

Am I missing a function or usability? When I do change a file the file and the above folder turn light blue in PhpStorm - when I save it goes away.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check if git is enabled for specific folder? Go to File > settings > Version control and make sure your project folder has git.[image]

Comment: Try to execute in console "git log". You must see commit history.